# How to put timedelta in django model?

Tags: django

With inspectdb I was able to get a "interval" field from postgres into django. In Django, it was a TextField. The object that I retrieved was indeed a timedelta object!

Now I want to put this timedelta object in a new model. What's the best way to do this? Because putting a timedelta in a TextField results in the str version of the object...

Comment: Since Django 1.8 you can use DurationField.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can trivially normalize a timedelta to a single floating-point number in days or seconds.

Here's the "Normalize to Days" version.

```
float(timedelta.days) + float(timedelta.seconds) / float(86400)
```

You can trivially turn a floating-point number into a timedelta.

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(2.5)
datetime.timedelta(2, 43200)
```

So, store your timedelta as a float.

Here's the "Normalize to Seconds" version.

```
timedelta.days*86400+timedelta.seconds
```

Here's the reverse (using seconds)

```
datetime.timedelta( someSeconds/86400 )
```

Comment: off course you mean float(timedelta.days) + float(timedelta.seconds)/float(86400) ... but it works!

Comment: timedelta.days+timedelta.seconds/86400.0

Comment: Since python 2.7 you can normalize to seconds using the [timedelta.total_seconds](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method.

Answer (score 111):

Since Django 1.8 you can use [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField).

Comment: SO on how to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222660/how-should-i-use-durationfield-in-my-model

Answer (score 8):

First, define your model:

```
class TimeModel(models.Model):
    time = models.FloatField()
```

To store a timedelta object:

```
# td is a timedelta object
TimeModel.objects.create(time=td.total_seconds())
```

To get the timedelta object out of the database:

```
# Assume the previously created TimeModel object has an id of 1
td = timedelta(seconds=TimeModel.objects.get(id=1).time)
```

**Note:** I'm using Python 2.7 for this example.

Comment: on python with version lower than 2.7 can be used formula:  `total_seconds = (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6`

Comment: This is great.  Thank you for being both concise and thorough

Answer (score 7):

https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-timedelta-field/src

Comment: In a repository: check. Works: check. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: no longer available, I got a 404

Answer (score 4):

There is a ticket which dates back to July 2006 relating to this:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2443

Several patches were written but the one that was turned in to a project:
https://github.com/johnpaulett/django-durationfield

Compared to all the other answers here this project is mature and would have been merged to core except that its inclusion is currently considered to be "bloaty".

Personally, I've just tried a bunch of solutions and this is the one that works beautifully.

```
from django.db import models
from durationfield.db.models.fields.duration import DurationField

class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = DurationField()

    @property
    def finish(self):
        return self.start + self.duration
```

Result:

```
$ evt = Event.objects.create(start=datetime.datetime.now(), duration='1 week')
$ evt.finish
Out[]: datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 13, 5, 29, 29, 404753)
```

And in admin:

**Change event**

Duration: `7 days, 0:00:00`

Comment: It looks like in Django 1.8, that ticket will finally be closed and Django will have a `DurationField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#new-data-types

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL, use django-pgsql-interval-field here: http://code.google.com/p/django-pgsql-interval-field/

Answer (score 2):

Putting this out there cause it might be another way to solve this problem.
first install this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-timedeltafield

Then:

```
import timedelta

class ModelWithTimeDelta(models.Model):
    timedeltafield = timedelta.fields.TimedeltaField()
```

within the admin you will be asked to enter data into the field with the following format: 3 days, 4 hours, 2 minutes

Comment: I prefer this solution with Django 1.7 because it's in the pip repo and not an external source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297988/9070016). If you're using Postgresql, then multiplying the result of `F` expression with `timedelta` solves the problem. For example if you have a `start_time` and a `duration` in minutes, you can calculate the `end_time` like this:

```py
YourModel.objects.annotate(
    end_time=ExpressionWrapper(F('start_time') + timedelta(minutes=1) * F('duration'), output_field=DateTimeField())
)
```