# Django: Using F arguments in datetime.timedelta inside a query

Tags: django, model, typeerror, timedelta

Using Django model syntax, if I do this:

```
ThatModel.objects.filter(
    last_datetime__lte=now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=F("interval")))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: ExpressionNode
```

Is there a way to make this work with pure Django syntax (and not parsing all the results with Python)?

Comment: I have some queries, what type of object is `now`, is "interval" is a integer field and what is its value?? Thanks

Comment: `now` is a datetime.datetime object.  The `interval` field is an IntegerField, and its value is 5.

Comment: You can do that, Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42390145/4070498) my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From django docs:

> `Django` provides F expressions to allow such comparisons. Instances
>   of F() act as a reference to a model field within a query. These
>   references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of
>   two different fields on the same model instance.

That means you can use `F()` for comparing within queries. `F()` returns reference so when you use it as parameter for `timedelta` object, you get the error `ExpressionNode`. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). You might check the source code of [F()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/428c0bbe1bcd303560d7e96d7d2721ff3fdc0e3f/django/db/models/expressions.py)

For your solution, you can check this: [DateModifierNode](https://github.com/django/django/blob/428c0bbe1bcd303560d7e96d7d2721ff3fdc0e3f/django/db/models/expressions.py), or just save the value of `interval` elsewhere and then pass it as parameter of `timedelta`.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid - asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703016/what-is-the-replacement-for-datemodifiernode-in-new-versions-of-django

Answer (score 47):

## Just avoid `timedelta`'s `F`-ignorance

`filter` knows about `F`, but `timedelta` does not.
The trick is to keep the `F` out of the `timedelta` argument list:

```
ThatModel.objects.filter(
    last_datetime__lte=now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)*F("interval"))
```

This [will work with PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html), but, alas, not with SQlite.