# Django Filter by ForeignKey value

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-filter

Suppose I have two models

```
class DocumentType(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    exp_days = models.PositiveIntegerField("Remind me before (Days)", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Document(BaseModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey("masters.DocumentType", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_of_expiry = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    attachment = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)
```

How can I retrieve documents with expiry dates that match a specified number of days (represented by `{exp_days}`) from today? I have a filter like this for documents expiring in the next 30 days:

```
documents = Document.objects.filter(date_of_expiry__lte=today+timedelta(days=30))
```

How can I adapt this filter to match the number of days specified by `{exp_days}`?

Comment: exact same condition to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) object that represents the value of a model field. so to reference `exp_days` from related model you can use `F('type__exp_days')`

An answer from [Lutz Prechelt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297988/5937348) shows how to move the F() expression outside the timedelta.

Here is the modified code

```
from django.db.models import F

documents = Document.objects.filter(date_of_expiry__lte=today+timedelta(days=1)*F('type__exp_days'))
```

As mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html), this will work with PostgreSQL but, might not with other DBs (Not confirmed).

Comment: `timedelta` is probably `datetime.timedelta` you can't pass an `F` object to that...

Comment: Oh yes, but here is a workaround

`documents = Document.objects.filter(date_of_expiry__lte=today+timedelta(days=1)*F('type__exp_days'))`

Also updated my answer