# Can a Django query filter with a relationship reference a parent's field value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Training and TrainingAssignment table in my django app. Users sign into the app and complete a Training which creates a TrainingAssignment record.  The Training table has a field, `days_valid` which is used to determine whether or not a user has to re-take a training.

I want an admin to be able to change `days_valid` on the fly to "invalidate" previously completed trainings.  (e.g. changing a training thats good for a year to only good for one month.). I don't want the admin's changing of `days_valid` to go out and change the expiration date of thr TrainingAssignment record...I want those records to remain untouched for audit purposes. Instead, my code creates a new assignment if the employee is due.

`models.py`

```
class Training(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    days_valid = models.IntegerField()


class TrainingAssignment(models.Model):
    training = models.ForeignKey(
        Training,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='training_assignments',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    date_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True) 
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_expires = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In a query, I need to be able to get all Trainings where TrainingAssignment's `date_completed` + the Training's `days_valid` <= today.  (ie. user completes a TrainingAssignment on 6/1/23 and it's Training record is valid for 45 days, so when they log in on 6/15/23 the queryset should be empty but on 7/19/23 the queryset should contain that training.)

```
now = timezone.now().date()    
trainings = Training.objects.filter(
    training_assignments__date_completed__lte=now+datetime.timedelta(days=training_assigments__training.days_valid))
```

But this obviously errors out with `training_assignments__training.days_valid is undefined`

Can a query reference a field of itself? I am not even sure of the right question to ask.
Part of me feels I am overcomplicating this.  Another part of me feels the Django-ORM already solved this problem and I just haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Where *any* `TrainingAssignment` mets this constraint, or *all*?

Comment: I’m not sure that distinction matters? I’m getting all trainings unless there’s a related TrainingAssignment that has passed the validation (date_completed + Training.days_valid >= today) @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Of course that matters: imagine you have a `Training` with two `TrainingAssignment`s and one is valid and the other is not.

Comment: I’d want all invalid trainings

Comment: Check out F Expressions. They let you use model values in filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Postgres as your database and really want this as a single query, you can use an F() Expression to get the `days_valid` from the Training instance related to the TrainingAssignment. The filter subtracts the `days_valid` from today's date and compares that with the `date_completed` of each TrainingAssignment to find any that have expired. After we run the filter, we use `values_list` to tell Django to only get the field that we're interested in (Training), and then we use `distinct` to remove redundancies.

Note that the F() Expression can't be used directly inside `timedelta`, so we create a 1-day `timedelta` and multiply by the F() Expression ([credit to Lutz Prechelt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297988/12735064))

```py
from django.db.models import F

now = timezone.now().date()    
trainings = TrainingAssignment.objects.filter(date_completed__lte=now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) * F("training__days_valid")).values_list("training__title", flat=True).distinct()
```

This won't work for SQLite because of the F() Expression multiplication with datetime.timedelta. You can use the loop below to accomplish the same without the F() Expression.

```py
needed_trainings = []
now = timezone.now().date() 
for training in Training.objects.all():
     if TrainingAssignment.objects.filter(training=training, date_completed__lte=now - datetime.timedelta(days=training.days_valid)).exists():
         needed_trainings.append(training.title)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid a loop but in this situation it is easier to read.  Might go with that and optimize if needed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question.

```
Training.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        TrainingAssignments.objects.filter(
            training=OuterRef("pk"),
            date_completed__lte=now + datetime.timedelta(days=OuterRef("days_valid")),
        )
    )
)
```

What does this do:

1. `days=OuterRef("days_valid")` and `OuterRef("pk")` retrieve the days_valid of the Training and the Training of that TrainingAssignment from the outer query
2. The `Exists(...)` returns a boolean which will then be used to retrieve the trainings that match the inner query

I tried an almost similar query on some tables I have and it worked fine but you'll need to test the exact one.

You can read more on the expressions I have used here [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions)