# How should I use DurationField in my model?

Tags: django, django-models

In my model I want to be able to input duration, like *2 years*, *5 months*, etc.

In version 1.8 DurationField was introduced so I tried using that:

In my model I have

```
user_validPeriod = models.DurationField()
```

Trying to add a new *User* from my admin panel, If I try typing something like *2d* or *2 days* in the appearing text-field though I get `Enter a valid duration`.

[image]

Can someone provide me with an example of how this field is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To use a DurationField in django 1.8 you have to use a python `datetime.timedelta` instance like this:

Considering this model :

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

You can set a duration this way :

```
import datetime
    
my_model = MyModel()
my_model.duration = datetime.timedelta(days=20, hours=10)
```

And query it this way :

```
# Equal
durations = MyModel.objects.filter(duration=datetime.timedelta(*args, **kwargs))

# Greater than or equal
durations = MyModel.objects.filter(duration__gte=datetime.timedelta(*args, **kwargs))

# Less than or equal
durations = MyModel.objects.filter(duration__lte=datetime.timedelta(*args, **kwargs))
```

More info on datetime.timedelta [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) and on DurationField [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField).

In your admin panel, you can enter a duration with a string with following format : `[DD] [[hh:]mm:]ss`

Comment: Hi Charlesthk, in your answer you haven't used DurationField at all. Not to mention that I cant find an example of someone using it. What is the purpose of its existence if no one uses it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am sure it is as explicit as it can possibly get, but this is my first time using Django so you will have to excuse my ignorance. The way I know until now to add values to my model, and the way I would expect an administrator or user to do so is through the form in the admin panel?

Comment: Yes you can use the admin for that ! If the answer is ok to you you can accept it ;-)

Comment: Well the issue is that I cannot. I updated the question hopefully making it more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77750/discussion-between-charlesthk-and-green-leaf).

Comment: In the end I made you cough up everything you knew on this :) Im sorry for that. I do realise in the end though that this is probably not what I want to use. I am interested in periods of years and months not hours.

Comment: @ealiaj  I am also in the same need. I want to have a period input in terms of number of years and months. How you did that ? I am thinking of having integer field to store duration in months and then showing in terms of year and months to user. While saving, I will convert year + months in total months. Is this correct approach or some other options is there ?

Comment: if you want to work with a really custom format like years and months only, I'd advise to override an IntegerField  or CharField model, you could also apply javascript to the form field. The problem is that with DurationField, it doesn't really let you have much control over changing the output ISO time format