# Django ORM - get records that are older than record's `duration` days

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the model:

```py
class Plan(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField()
  duration = models.DurationField(default=30)
```

I want to get the records that are older than `today - duration` with ORM. Is it possible? Maybe something like `Plan.objects.filter(date__lt='self.duration')` exists?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

Comment: Thank you! Just found F expressions myself. Will post answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ivan Starostin mentioned in comment [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) are very useful:

```py
today = datetime.now()
plans = Plan.objects.filter(date__lt=today - F('duration'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this:

```
Plan.objects.filter(duration__lt='YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Consider I have a Product modal with the field created

```
class Product(models.Model):
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     #other fields

Product.objects.filter(created__lt='2019-05-15')
```

Comment: Can you provide some exmaples? I didn't understand what did you mean and how it is done.

Comment: Oh, I see. But you didn't get the main point of my question. It was about how to querry against the field that is part of the record itself. And one of fileds is DurationField - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#durationfield

Comment: Ok got . I am not that much expert but this link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222660/how-should-i-use-durationfield-in-my-model