# DurationField or Timedelta

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

im having a problem trying to set a duration in my to-do tasks.

i've tried with DurationField and some people told me to try the timedelta in your forms.py but im not quite shure how to pass the difference like (6days) from my two model DateField (start and end).

Models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



class To_do (models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    how = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    start = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    end = models.DateField(blank=False)
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
```

i'd like to display the difference for the user and after set an alarm for less than 3 days etc.

How do I solve this?

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222660/how-should-i-use-durationfield-in-my-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between two date or date/time values is a timedelta.

```
delta_time = end - start
```

Or if you need to code a delta-time constant from other numbers

```
from datetime import timedelta

my_delta = timedelta( days=3, hours=12, minutes=1 ) # half a week plus a minute
```

Don't use `timedelta` as the name as the default value if you are importing it! If what you mean to do is to pass a callable to calculate a timedelta, define a function to do that as above, and pass it as the default value.