# Django admin list_filter return ''str' object has no attribute 'days' for DurationField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin-filters

I am using DurationField in my model's field. The issue arises when I try to use this DurationField in list_filter in Django admin. Filtering based on this DurationField results in ''str' object has no attribute 'days'. I am using sqlite3 and Django 2.2.4. How can I overcome this problem? I need to be able to use DurationField in my Django admin filter.

I have checked the Debug page result and it shows that the value is returned as a string. Why is being returned as a string and not in timedelta format? Below is the snippet of the DEBUG page. The value is in string and thus it fails.

**connection**

```
<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7ff7ca6a2e80>

prepared    
True
self    

<django.db.models.fields.DurationField: average_length>

value   
'1:22:22'
```

Below is how my model is:

```
class VideoSeries(models.Model):
average_length = models.DurationField()
```

I just want to be able to filter based on average_length which is a duration field. Is there any customization to be done for DurationField?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might find some more useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222830/1037971

You're just getting the to_string result of it. You can filter on a Duration Field using a `datetime.timedelta` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. i got it fixed after some research based on ur comments..