# Which django field should be used for a time counter? ACTUAL

Tags: django, django-models

I need a field in the model for a required work hours. For example, with default value 40 hours. Which field I should use?

UPD

When I use:

```
required_work_hours = models.DurationField(_('Required work hours'), blank=True, null=True,
                                           default=timedelta(hours=40))
```

I get a value `1 16:00:00` instead of 40 hours

P.S.

I have already have `start_time` and `end_time`. I should have a value to compare with `end_time - start_time`

Comment: What is the resolution? One hour? One minute? Ten minutes?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 1 hour

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PositiveSmallIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) if you are planning on storing whole hours (not minutes, seconds). Like most Django `ModelField`s, you can set a default value (which I guess is 40 in your case).

You can use [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) as well. It accepts `datetime.timedelta` values. So, it can *store* days, hours, seconds.

Refer to [How should I use DurationField in my model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222660/how-should-i-use-durationfield-in-my-model) SO entry for usage of `DurationField`.

> I have already have `start_time` and `end_time`.

Well, in that case: assuming both these fields are of type `DateTimeField`, then `end_time - start_time` should give you `datetime.timedelta` instance. This `datetime.timedelta` instance can be then converted into hours.

Code for that will be something as follows:

```
delta = end_time - start_time
hours = (delta.days * 24) + (delta.seconds // 3600)
```

Answer (score 1):

With using integer like date, I feel some information is lost.

I'd model it with `work_start_time` and `work_end_time`. You can use `DateTimeField`, set defaults and add a calculated filed on model that looks at these two dates to calculate hours. Something to think about.

Comment: I have already have `start_time` and `end_time`. I should have a value to compare with `end_time - start_time`

Comment: The work hours value you compare with could be a value that's added when you create that employee? I'd be careful even in that case and check if number of hours people work can change over time. Additionally, 40 hours as a standard is slowly changing. People are working in shifts and enterprises experimenting with 4 day work weeks.

Comment: It is not could be a value that's added when you create that employee. It is HAVE TO BE that value. In Ukraine situation with 40 hours as a standard will change not soon:)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a [**`PositiveSmallIntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) to store small integers. Django guarantees that the minimum range is:

> Like a `PositiveIntegerField`, but only allows values under a certain (database-dependent) point. **Values from 0 to 32767** are safe in all databases supported by Django.

So the number of hours per week can be represented, since there are 168 hours per week. Furhtmore Django will validate that the number is positive, so that means it will raise an error in the form if you enter a negative number.

You can furthermore enrich this with a validator, for example:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    hours = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(168, 'There are only 168 hours a week.')],
        default=40
    )
```

Here it will thus store the number of hours as an integer. That means that you can store 39, 40, or 41, but not 40.5 for example.

For a generic duration, you can make use of a [**`DurationField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#durationfield). This converts values at the Python level to `timedelta` objects, and at the database level it uses an `interval` on a *PostgreSQL* database, on Oracle an `INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(6)`, and on other databases, it will behind the curtains use a `bigint`. The advantage of this is however that it thus represents the duration as a `timedelta`, which makes it convenient to for example do arithmetic with `datetime` objects.