# Django model elapsed time between two DateTimeFields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am pretty new to django and haven't been able to find a way to get the elapsed time between two DateTimeFields and save it to another model.

```html
from django.db import models



class Timesheet(models.Model):
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    endTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.DateTimeField(endTime - startTime)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.startTime
```

How can I make duration = endTime - startTime?
I am also using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Do you mean you need `duration = endTime - startTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a dedicated model field for the duration.

I would use a property on the model instead for the same functionality.

Something like:

```
@property
def duration(self)
    return self.end_time - self.startime
```

Lucas has a good idea of using an annotation, but if you have a Timesheet instance somewhere that didn't come from that object manager and was not previously annotated, you would have to do a separate database hit to actually annotate it.

This property is used as such:

```
some_timesheet_instance.duration
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to compute the `duration` field at query time for each object in the queryset

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, fields    

timesheets = Timesheet.objects.annotate(
    duration=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('endTime') - F('startTime'),
        output_field=fields.DurationField()
    )
)

timesheets[0].duration  # datetime.timedelta(0, 722, 18373)
```

Is possible perform another queryset methods over annotations like `filter()`, `order_by()`, `aggregate()`, etc.

```
timesheets.order_by('-duration')  
timesheets.aggregate(Avg('duration')) # {'duration__avg': datetime.timedelta(0, 26473, 292625)}
```

Comment: Where do I place this code? If I put it into my models.py I get an error saying Models aren't loaded yet. Does this go into my views or am I missing something?

Comment: This code must be executed when you perform a query (don't put in your `models.py`), the `duration` field will be added at query-time

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = timesheet.end_time - timesheet.start_time
```

When you substract two datetime instances you don't get another datetime instance but a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) instace, which is just the days, seconds and microseconds difference between the two datetimes. You can't store a timedelta in a DateTimefield, but you can use an IntegerField, for example:

```
days_in_seconds = duration.days * 86400   # days difference by seconds in a day
duration_in_seconds = duration.seconds + days_in_seconds  # duration in seconds
```

When you want to access the duration as timedelta you just do:

```
import datetime

duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=timesheet.duration)
```

You can also store it as FloatField as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801912/how-to-put-timedelta-in-django-model).